# How to find invertible matrix $P$ Such that $B=P^{-1}AP$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

> Let $A,B$ be the two $3 \times 3$ matrices
>
> $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
> 3 & 2 &-5\\2 &6&-10\\1 &2 & -3 \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> $$B=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 6 &20 &-34\\6 &32&-51\\4 &20 &-32 \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>
> Suppose that there is a Non Singular matrix $P$ that $P^{-1}AP=B$. Find $P$

My idea is using Eigen Values we get Diagonilization of Matrices $A$ and $B$ as:

$$A=RD_AR^{-1}$$

$$B=QD_BQ^{-1}$$

Then we get:

$$QD_BQ^{-1}=P^{-1}RD_AR^{-1}P$$

But i feel this is very tedious procedure?

Comment: If $B=P^{-1}AP$, then $A$ and $B$ are similar, and they have the same eigenvalues. Notice that here, $A$ and $B$ have indeed the same eigenvalue $2$ with multiplicity $3$, but neither is diagonalizable. You may rely on Jordan decomposition instead.

Comment: Probably he could Jordanize, but that's more tedious too :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $$P=\begin{bmatrix} a & b& c \\ u & v& w\\ x & y & z \end{bmatrix}$$
$$PB=AP.$$
Then set up 9 linear simultaneous  homogeneous equations for $a,b,...y,z$ as
$$C_{9 \times 9} X_{9\times 1} =O_{9\times 1}$$
many solutions will exist for $X$, from a vector $X$, one can then determine a matrix $P$. The matric $P$ will be non-unique. The matrix $C$ will have its $\det|C|=0$ as zero, otherwise $X=O.$

Comment: "unique solution"; Is it  a joke ?

Comment: @ Oh ! yes, soy you are right many solutions, You may see ny edit.

Answer (score 1):

When we don't know explicitly the eigenvalues, there are two methods

1. We solve the equation $PB=AP$; the space of solutions has dimension $dim(C(A))$ where $C(A)$ is the commutant of $A$ (here $5$). The general solution is in the form $P=a_1P_1+\cdots+a_5P_5$ where the $(P_i)$ are known matrices.  We randomly choose the coefficients $(a_i)$ and we obtain (with probability $1$) an invertible matrix $P$ and we are done (of course, if your matrix $P$ is not invertible, then you start again for free).
2. We calculate the Frobenius normal forms (with a PC, it's very fast) $A=QFQ^{-1},B=RFR^{-1}$ (with the same $F$) and we deduce $P$.

Yet, here we know $spectrum(A)=\{2,2,2\}$ and that  $dim(\ker(A-2I))=2$.

$e_1=(1,0,0)$ is not in $\ker(A-2I)$ or in $\ker(B-2I)$ and $e_2=(B-2I)(e_1)=[4,6,4]^T\in \ker(B-2I),e'_2=(A-2I)(e_1)=[1,2,1]^T\in\ker(A-2I)$.

We complete the bases of $\ker(B-2I),\ker(A-2I)$ with $e_3=[-5,1,0]^T$ and $e'_3=[-2,1,0]^T$.

We choose $P$ s.t. $P(e_1)=e_1,P(e_2)=e'_2,P(e_3)=e'_3$.

Finally $P\begin{pmatrix}1&4&-5\\0&6&1\\0&4&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-2\\0&2&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $P=\begin{pmatrix}1&3&-21/4\\0&1&-1\\0&0&1/4\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can do it by solving a single explicit 9 by 9 system (also tedious but straightforward!).

Indeed, call $p_i =Pe_i$. Note that $p_i^l =P_{il}$ cause we are using standard basis vectors. Here $p_i^l$ denotes the $l$ component of $p_i$.

We have $A=PBP^{-1}$. Applying these matrices to $p_i$ and taking the k-th component we get:

- LHS: $(Ap_i)_k = \sum A_{kl} p_i^l$
- RHS: $(PBe_i)_k = (P\sum B_{ij} e_j)_k = (\sum B_{ij} Pe_j)_k = \sum B_{ij} p_j^k$

By equating LHS and RHS we get 9 equations (varying $i,k$) in 9 variables (the $p_i^l$'s). As far as I know, you should solve 6 linear system 3x3 to find the eigenvectors, so this should be faster.

Comment: You solve your system of $9$ equations. And after ? Do you think that you are done?

Comment: You don't understand. Your solution must be invertible!

Comment: The problem explicitly state: suppose that there exist a non singular matrix such that..

Comment: You must work my friend... Indeed, your system has an infinity of solutions; some are invertible and some are not. The OP asks for an explicit invertible solution.

Comment: Even then, $P$ such that $AP=PB$ can be singular. If only because $P=0$ is a solution. Actually, when you solve the $9\times9$ system, you get $5$ parameters and you can solve for the other $4$ variables (the coefficients of $P$). But then, you have to choose carefully those $5$ parameters so that the determinant does not vanish. With one choice of parameters, the determinant of $P$ is $$\frac15 (2 p_{11}+3 p_{12}+2 p_{13})^2 (10 p_{11}-2 p_{12}-5
   p_{21}+p_{22})$$

Comment: Ok, I get it. You are saying that I am just parametrising the "commutator" of the two. @jean-claude: are you saying that the kernel of the system has dimension 5?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Don't know if this can help, but I found out that the dimension of invertible P's such that the condition holds is 3, so we have a gap of two.

Comment: I'd like to know how you find a "dimension" for something that is not a linear space (if it were, the null matrix should be regular, but it's not). The $5$ I give above is the dimension of the linear space of matrices $P$ that satisfy $AP=PB$, $P$ being regular or not (it's easy to see it's indeed a linear space). The remaining conditions on the determinant are that two linear combinations of the elements of $P$ (see the two factors above), are **not** equal to $0$.

Comment: It is the dimension as a subvariety of GL. Indeed, you can easily show that the Jordan form of the matrices is one 2x 2 Jordan block and a 1x1 block. Things that satisfy $XAX^{-1} = B$ are equal to $PY$, where $P$ is the one we look for and $Y$ is such that $YAY^{-1}=A$. Wlog $A$ is in Jordan form by the same reasoning. Here we can explicitly compute that good invertible matrices have the form $(a \ a(1+b)\  0 // 0\  ab\  0 // 0\ 0\ c)$ with $a,b,c$ different by zero, so that the dimension is 3 :)

Comment: Well, with the condition on the deterimnant I mention above, take the following for $P$: $$\left(
\begin{matrix}
 p_{11} & p_{12} & p_{13} \\
 p_{21} & p_{22} & 2 p_{11}+3 p_{12}+2 p_{13}-p_{21}-\frac{3p_{22}}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{5} (-3 p_{11}-6 p_{12}-4 p_{13}+2 p_{21}) & \frac{1}{5} (-20p_{11}-29 p_{12}-20 p_{13}+2 p_{22}) & \frac{1}{5} (38 p_{11}+57p_{12}+39 p_{13}-2 p_{21}-3 p_{22}) \\
\end{matrix}
\right)$$

Comment: Don't see what you are arguing. However, I am posting an answer based on different methods. Btw, seems like you two do not want to have a constructive discussion! Generally I like to talk freely until an idea comes out from the community :)

Comment: I'm just showing you there are $5$ parameters in this expression for $P$, nothing more. Since it's basically the solution to the system you write in your post, seems constructive enough to me. I didn't intend to upset you.

Comment: Ok, sorry if I misunderstood you! However, I am posting a solution using simple matrices that is theorically shorter, but probably involves big numbers and this is not pleasant. Maybe we could manage together to find some trickier passages not to involve big numbers :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an ad-hoc method that works for almost simple matrices. It is optimized for dimension 3. If you dont want to see the proof, skip at the end to see the recipe for computation.

**Definition**. A simple matrix is a matrix that can be written as $v w^T$ for some vectors $v,w$. In particular $(v w^T)_{ij} = v_i w_j$.
If you know what tensors are, I called it simple because it corresponds to a simple tensor $v \otimes w$ in the correspondence $Hom(W,V) \simeq W^* \otimes V$.

*Observation.* A matrix $M$ is simple if and only if the rows are all scalar multiples of the same vector. In this case, for a choice of $M_{11} = ab$, we have that $M =uv^T$ where $v$ is the first row divided by $a$, and $u$ is the first column divided by $b$.

**First step**: reduce to a simple matrix. Note that 
$$ A = 2I + uv^T, B= 2I + wz^T$$
where $u= (1\ \  2\ \  1), v = (1\ \ 2\ \ -5), w=(2 \ \  3\ 2), z=(2\ \ 10 \ \  -17) $. 
To check this computation, use the observation with $A_{11} = 1 \cdot 1, B_{11} = 2 \cdot 2$. Set $C= uv^T, D=wz^T$ for the corresponding simple matrices.

Suppose that we find a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}(uv^T)P = wz^T$. Then
$$ P^{-1}AP = P^{-1}( uv^T + 2I)P = P^{-1}(uv^T)P + 2P^{-1}P = wz^T+2I = B$$
So we would be done.

**Second step**: reduce to matrices with same frobenius norm.

Next paragraph will explain why this step is necessary. Recall that the frobenius norm $\| \cdot \|$ is the norm of the matrix seen as a vector, i.e. the square root of the sum of squared components.

Use a matrix of the form $X_{\lambda} = \text{diag}( \lambda\ \  1 \ \ 1)$ with $\lambda \neq 0$ to conjugate $C$. You will get 
$$\| X_{\lambda^{-1}} C X_{\lambda} \|^2 = C_{11}^2 + \lambda^2(C_{12}^2 + C_{13}^2) + \lambda^{-2}(C_{21}^2 + C_{31}^2) + (\sum_{i,j>1} C_{ij}^2) $$

Note that the frobenius norm of $D$ is strictly greater than the frobenius norm of $C$ (the expression above for $\lambda=1$). Moreover, this expression in lambda goes to infinity for $\lambda \to \infty$, so that there exist a $\lambda$ such that

$$\| X_{\lambda^{-1}}C X_{\lambda} \|^2 = \| D \|^2$$

You can find it by solving a quadratic equation.
Also, note that $X_{\lambda^{-1}}C X_{\lambda} = (X_{\lambda^{-1}}u)(X_{\lambda}v)^T$ is still a simple matrix. Set $\alpha = X_{\lambda^{-1}}u, \beta = X_{\lambda}v$

**Third step**: conjugating simple matrices with same frobenius norm.

Firstly, note that for a simple matrix

$$ \| u \|^2 \| v\|^2 = (\sum_i u_i^2 ) (\sum_j v_j^2 ) = \sum_{i,j} (u_iv_j)^2 = \| uv^T \|^2 $$

i.e. the frobenius norm is the product of the norms of the two vectors. 
We look for an orthogonal $Q$ such that $(Q\alpha)(Q^T\beta)^T = Q \alpha \beta^T Q^{-1} = wz^T$. It is enough if we find a $Q$ and a $\mu$ such that
$$ Q\alpha = \mu w, Q\beta = \mu^{-1} z$$

Taking norms and recalling that $Q$ is orthogonal:
$$ \| \alpha \| = \mu \| w\|, \| \beta \| = \mu^{-1} \| z \| $$
So that $\mu = \|\alpha\| / \|w\|$. Indeed, the second equation is satisfied by
$$\mu^{-1} \|z\| = \| w\| \| z\| / \|\alpha \| = \|wz^T \| / \|\alpha\| = \| \alpha \beta^T \| / \| \alpha \| = \| \beta\| $$

Now set $\gamma = \mu w, \delta = \mu^{-1} z$. Note that we have
$$\| \alpha\| = \|\gamma\|, \|\beta\| = \|\delta\|$$
$$ \langle \alpha, \beta \rangle = \text{tr}(\alpha \beta^T) = \text{tr}(uv^T) = \text{tr}(A) - \text{tr}(2I) = \text{tr}(B) -\text{tr}(2I) =\text{ tr}(wz^T) = \langle \gamma, \delta \rangle $$

There exist an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $Q \alpha = \gamma, Q \beta = \delta, Q( \alpha \times \beta) = Q(\gamma \times \delta)$. You can find this by an ordinary change of basis process.

**Recipe.** On balance, the process is the following:

1. As in first step, set $C=A-2I, D= B-2I$ and $u= (1\  2\  1), v = (1\ 2\ -5), w=(2 \ 3\ 2), z=(2\ 10 \ -17) $.
2. Solve the following biquadratic equation for $\lambda$:
   $$ C_{11}^2 + \lambda^2(C_{12}^2 + C_{13}^2) + \lambda^{-2}(C_{21}^2+C_{31}^2) + \sum_{i,j >1} C_{ij}^2 = \sum_{i,j} D_{ij}^2 $$
   And set $\alpha = (\lambda^{-1} \ 2 \ 1), \beta = (\lambda \ 2 \ -5)$.
3. Set $\mu = \| \alpha \| / \| w\| $, and $\gamma = \mu w, \delta = \mu^{-1}z$.
4. Find a base change $Q$ such that $Q \alpha = \gamma, Q \beta = \delta, Q (\alpha \times \beta) = \gamma \times \delta$.

Then your final matrix $P$ will be $P=Q^T \text{diag}(\lambda \ \ 1 \ \ 1)$.

*Pros and cons*: the pro is that you will just have to compute an explicit quadratic equation and a base change. The con is that probably big numbers will be involved!